# How to update a table using cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a procedure to update a column of a table Xyz if today date is between the start_date and end_date of table ABC.

```
table ABC

    fin_cycle    start_date   end_date    account_class
    ----------------------------------------------------

    F2018        27-05-2020    29-05-20    2003

table xyz
account_no    account_class  ac_no_dr

1234           2003             Y
```

when I run the procedure today and if today's date is between start_date and end date of table ABC then the procedure will update column ac_no_dr as Y, else it will update the column as N. I have prepared this skeleton.

```
Create Or Replace PROCEDURE pr_no_debit
     Cursor c_Today(start_date, end_Date) is
     Select Today from sttm_branch  where today between start_Date and end_Date;

   l_No_Debit_List   ABC%ROW_TYPE;
   Begin



     For c_Today(l_No_Debit_List.start_Date,l_No_Debit_List.end_Date) Loop  


       Update XYZ set ac_no_DR='Y' where account_class=l_No_Debit_List.account_class;

   End Loop;

     -- At the end of the period Change No_Debit to 'N'

   End pr_no_debit;
```

Comment: this code makes no sense.  l_No_Debit_List has no values.

Comment: So how can i write this procedure.. please help..

Comment: update XYZ x set ac_no_DR='Y' where (select count(*) from ABC a where a.account_class =x.account_class and trunc(sysdate) between a.start_date and a.end_date) > 0

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option: `merge`. (Today is 27.05.2020 which is between start and end date stored in the `abc` table).

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From abc;

FIN_C START_DATE END_DATE   ACCOUNT_CLASS
----- ---------- ---------- -------------
F2018 27.05.2020 29.05.2020          2003

SQL> select * From xyz;

ACCOUNT_NO ACCOUNT_CLASS A
---------- ------------- -
      1234          2003
```

Merge statement:

```
SQL> merge into xyz a
  2    using (select account_class,
  3                  case when sysdate between start_date and end_date then 'Y'
  4                       else 'N'
  5                  end ac_no_dr
  6           from abc
  7          ) x
  8    on (a.account_class = x.account_class)
  9    when matched then update set a.ac_no_dr = x.ac_no_dr;

1 row merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From xyz;

ACCOUNT_NO ACCOUNT_CLASS A
---------- ------------- -
      1234          2003 Y

SQL>
```

The bottom line: you don't need a procedure nor a loop (which is inefficient) as everything can be done with a single SQL statement.

---

If - as you commented - has to be a procedure, no problem either:

```
create or replace procedure p_merge as
begin
  merge into xyz a
  using (select account_class,
                case when sysdate between start_date and end_date then 'Y'
                     else 'N'
                end ac_no_dr
         from abc
        ) x
  on (a.account_class = x.account_class)
  when matched then update set a.ac_no_dr = x.ac_no_dr;
end;
/
```

Comment: I need a procedure because we need to run this through a scheduler which will run automatically after the every EOD.

Comment: OK, no problem. If you don't know how to make a procedure out of some statement, I did that for you - have a look, please.

Comment: I can not use sysdate , after every eod  in our application the date is getting update in a table i.e sttm_branch.. we need to take that today date from this table..

Comment: So don't use SYSDATE but date fetched from your table. What's the problem with that? I have no idea how STTM_BRANCH looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table SET field = value
where trunc(sysdate) between trunc(start_date) and trunc(end_date)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**